# How to suspend gif animation when the Button is deactivated and how to align center vertically the gif relative to a LWUIT Button?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I put animated `gif` into the Resource Editor. I created a Button based on this `gif` Image , and the Button has also a text :

```
r = Resources.open("/resources.res");
uploadImg = r.getImage("upload");
envoieBtn = new Button("Envoyer", uploadImg);
envoieBtn.setTextPosition(Label.BOTTOM);
envoieBtn.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
```

This Button is put in the main screen , and this Button is not enabled until the phone mobile database ( RecordStore ) is populated via the third Button ( second line first column in the captured image ) on the main screen.

My problem is that even if the `envoieBtn` Button is disabled then the gif Image on it is animated ( the red arrow is still moving upward ) ! So how to suspend the animation of the `gif` image ?

My second question is how to center the image within the Button because on the captured image we see that the gif is not centered like the Button text.

Here is the captured image :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can suspend animation by overriding animate in the button and avoiding the call to super, just always return false. The GIF will no longer animate (you can do that conditionally for disabled buttons).

Since alignment is determined by content you can't align a button with an image to one without an image since the location of the text is determined by the image. I suggest you create a transparent image object of the exact same size and assign it to the buttons that don't have an image on them.